# How to use tpl files in jsp or php?

Tags: jsp, smarty

I have downloaded a template zip archive to make a new website. But those files in zip are `.tpl` files. I'm working in NetBeans, so Basically I'm using jsp's.But I can use php instead.but How can I use these .tpl files in java or in PHP

Comment: I think a question that basically asks "How do I convert PHP to Java?" is way too broad. There isn't going to be a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: you can't.  Either switch to PHP and use the smarty template framework as the template designer intended, or use a different template intended for java.

Comment: if I use PHP then how can i use these tpl files in PHP.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/ is the website for using smarty templates (.tpl files) in php.  I would expect that the template package you downloaded would have instructions on this.